# Disable option once selected and keep track of previous options with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So I have an select option list in place and below is the php code to insert the option you select into the database, I have an active session in place and I need it to not allow you to pick the same option again based on if you picked it already then it should not be allowed to be picked again even if you log out of the session and log back in.

This is where I'm confused, pretty sure it will take some part of database work saving the prior picks but not sure how to go about it.

```
<?php    
if(isset($_POST['submitbtn'])) {
    $selection = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['selection']); 
    $mysqli->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO users selection VALUE $selection WHERE `id` = '$my_id'");
    $pick = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `users` SET `selection` = '$selection' WHERE `id` = '$my_id'");
    echo '<p>You have made a selection!</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Are your `<option>`'s in the `<select>` database driven, or are they hard-coded in the PHP/HTML?

Comment: You will have to store all previous choices, and check against that at every change.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure solved my own question, this seemed to work just fine.

```
<?php
// Inserts pick selection into DB in row of session user
if(isset($_POST['submitbtn'])) {
    $selection = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['selection']); 
    $dup = $mysqli->query("SELECT selection FROM users WHERE `id` = '$my_id'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($dup) > 0){
        echo '<p style="color:red;"><b>**You have already selected this team.** <br>Choose another!</b></p>';
    } else {
    $pick = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `users` SET `selection` = '$selection' WHERE `id` = '$my_id'");
    echo '<p>You have made a selection!</p>';
}   
}
?>
```